# How to create an XSD schema that allows documents to contain another schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

We are defining an `XSD` schema for a database that contains columns with schemata.

The schema imports http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd to allow the elements to reference the `schema` type. Visual Studio reports errors both inside the imported schema and the containing schema.

Is it possible to constrain an element to contain only a single valid `<schema>` element and its children?

Comment: The schema-for-schemas does some things that ordinary user schemas aren't allowed to do, for example it contains definitions of primitive types. Some schema processors therefore reject it; it sounds as if Visual Studio falls into this category. I'm not sure of the relevance of the question in your last paragraph.

Comment: The last paragraph had a key word missing due to markdown parsing - sorry. We are using interpreted CDATA to work around the schema errors at present.

Comment: If by "valid `<schema>` element you mean, valid according to the schema for XSD schema documents, then it's only possible if your validator allows you to import the s4sd, and it seems that yours doesn't. (Note: getting this to work in the Saxon schema processor was a significant challenge.)